# Add multiple datanodes to a docker-compose

Tags: hadoop, docker-compose

im having my first contact with Hadoop. I deployed a single datanode cluster using the [docker-hadoop][1] repository.I'm curious about how i can add more datanodes to this docker-compose file (shortened for clarity):

```
version: "3"

services:
  namenode:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-namenode:2.0.0-hadoop3.2.1-java8
    container_name: namenode
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 9870:9870
      - 9000:9000
    volumes:
      - hadoop_namenode:/hadoop/dfs/name
    environment:
      - CLUSTER_NAME=test
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env

  datanode:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-datanode:2.0.0-hadoop3.2.1-java8
    container_name: datanode
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - hadoop_datanode:/hadoop/dfs/data
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:9870"
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env
```

Should i just copy paste the previous one, such as :

```
  datanode2:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-datanode:2.0.0-hadoop3.2.1-java8
    container_name: datanode
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - hadoop_datanode:/hadoop/dfs/data
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:9870"
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env
```

Thanks in advance.
[1]: https://github.com/big-data-europe/docker-hadoop

Answer (score 0):

You should use a unique `container_name` and double check the env file for variables unique to one HDFS datanode, but yes, you'd copy that section.

However, your one host is a single point of failure, anyway, so setting up replication between two datanodes on one disk wouldn't be beneficial